# PostgreSQL: transform spatial column from PG_GEOMETRY to ST_GEOMETRY

Tags: postgis, postgresql, st-geometry

I have spatial Data stored in my PostgreSQL database as PostGIS Geometry (PG_GEOMETRY). It looks for example like this: 010100002031BF0D0000000000F989264152B81E057E6D5841

Now I would like to move this column to a database with ArcSDE schema, which uses ST_GEOMETRY.

Is this possible with a simple sql command, or a more difficult task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Export the geometry to eWKB/WKB or WKT and then import it in the other db using appropiate function for geometry from eWKB/WKB/WKT. For example for WKB use `ST_AsBinary` and `ST_SRID` in PostGIS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this worked extracting the PostGIS geometry column with ST_AsText and inserting it into the spatial column of a feature class with sde.st_geometry.